# Locus question that Im stuck on

Tags: locus

Show that the locus of a point, which moves so as always to be three times further from one fixed point than from another fixed point is a circle?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** We assume we are working in the plane. Let the two given fixed points be $(a,b)$ and
$(c,d)$.

By the Pythagorean Theorem, the distance of a point (x,y) from (a,b) is
$$\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}.$$
The distance of $(x,y)$ from $(c,d)$ is 
$$\sqrt{(x-c)^2+(y-d)^2}.$$
The distance condition says that 
$$\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}=3\sqrt{(x-c)^2+(y-d)^2}.$$
Square both sides, bring all terms to one side, divide by $8$, You will get a familiar kind of equation.

Comment: You may as well shift the points so that $(a,b) = (0,0)$ and $(c,d) = (0,d)$. In other words, the first point is at the origin, and the second point is somewhere on the $x$-axis. Then you can do what Andre said, but the algebra will be a lot easier.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: I believe 'missile dragon' should be banned from maths stackexchange